# Prototypes chain differences between Firefox and Chrome console

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-chrome-devtools, prototype

When we try to log a **custom prototypes chain**, made with **custom constructor functions**, the Chrome console will display it in a very **illogical way**.

Here is the code where I create two constructor functions and chain the Italian's constructor with the Human one.

```js
// Constructor 1 : Human
function Human(arm, leg) {
    this.arm = arm;
    this.leg = leg
}
Human.prototype.think = function () {
    console.log("Think")
}

// Constructor 2 : Italian
function Italian(name) {
    this.name = name
}

// Adding Human.prototype to the prototypes chain.
Object.setPrototypeOf(Italian.prototype, Human.prototype)

// Adding some content for the sake of it
Italian.prototype.lang = "Italian"
Italian.prototype.cookPasta = function () {
    console.log("")
}
Italian.prototype.makePizza = function () {
    console.log("")
}
const italian = new Italian("Giovanni Madazzo")
console.log(italian)
```

And here is the **result** on Chrome console.

[image]

What is even more intriguing is that **it is not happening with the built-in constructors** (Array, Function, Number, etc...).

When we use a simple array, we can clearly see its prototype, *logically presented*.

Even though built-in constructors inherit from Object too, they do also have a prototypes chain.

```js
console.log([1,2,3])
```

[image]

The above looks perfectly **understandable**, we can literally open each of the link of the prototype chain with its corresponding name.

To finish, I want to point out that Firefox decided to take another path and to always show it in a logical way, built-in and non built-in constructors.

[image]

■
So, **why is Chrome doing this** ? And why doing this **especially** with the custom constructors function and not the built-in ones ?